# Lagged Sales for every product

Tags: python, pandas

Good Evening,

I have the following dataframe:

```
print(dd)
dt_op      quantity   product_code
20/01/18      1            613
21/01/18      8            611
21/01/18      1            613 
...
```

I am trying to get the lagged Sales, but the following code does **not** compute them by product_code as well:

```
dd["Lagged_Sales"] = [dd.loc[dd['dt_op'].between(d - pd.Timedelta(days = 15), d), 'quantity'].sum() \
                for d in dd['dt_op']]
```

I would like to define dd["Lagged_Sales"] as **sum of "quantity" sold in the past 15 days, for **every different** product in stock;

**ultimately, for i in *"dt_op"* and *"product_code"*.**

print(final_dd)

```
dt_op      quantity   product_code     Lagged Sales
20/01/18      1            613               1
21/01/18      8            611               8
21/01/18      1            613               2
...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rolling` with a `15d` frequency:

```
df.set_index('dt_op').groupby('product_code').rolling('15d').quantity.sum()

product_code  dt_op
611           2018-01-21    8.0
613           2018-01-20    1.0
              2018-01-21    2.0
Name: quantity, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Oh, I think a rolling window does make better sense.

Comment: Question is a bit ambiguous, I like your answer too, I think the question could use some clarification

Comment: What if I would like to get the following 15 days? Instead of "-" in the old code, between(d,  d + pd.Timedelta(days = 15)

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you mean.  If you want to sum the entire 15 day period, this answer won't do that (it does a rolling sum that looks behind 15 days), and you'd want to use [coldspeeds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51912919/3483203).

Comment: I would like a function that is capable of looking at the past(as required in the question) and the future (the next "N" days on the dataset)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, group with `pd.Grouper` and "product_code":

```
df.dt_op = pd.to_datetime(df.dt_op, errors='coerce')
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='dt_op', freq='15D'), 'product_code']).quantity.sum()

dt_op       product_code
2018-01-20  611             8
            613             2
Name: quantity, dtype: int64
```

Comment: It raises: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli If the dataframe in the question is not an accurate representation of your actual data, then I need something that is.

Comment: It is indeed; there may be a problem not related to it.